# Is it possible to send message via GTalk Intent?

Tags: android, xmpp, google-talk

I'm looking for a solution to send multicast (text) messages to all my google contacts from my android app. Is there a way to do this with the GTalk App (Intent), or do i have to use my own xmpp implementation? Any recommendations for an appropriate solution/framework besides gtalk piggybacking? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Hi Android already share a Service to do what you want, please check this URL

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/11/14/sending-xmpp-messages-in-android-standalone-sample-ant-buildxmlintellij-project/

Which explain very well what you want.

Have fun

Comment: As noted below, that service was removed in Android 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use asmack - http://code.google.com/p/asmack/?

Early Android SKD:s (before 1.0) contained a XMPP service, but that was removed in 1.0 - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/08/some-information-on-apis-removed-in.html.